# Profiling Android app for memory usage

Tags: android, eclipse, performance

Is there something in Eclipse or possibly a 3rd party tool that lets me see how my app is using up memory while it is running? When my app runs, there appears to be something that over time starts eating up memory. It would be nice to see what class is responsible for it so that I can zoom in on the area that is causing the problem. It would be nice to see how memory is being used dynamically over time and what know what classes/methods are "leaking".

Comment: Eclipse MAT plugin + read about it and how to use it with Android (DDMS -> Dump HPROF File)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. check the last part of the video. Use MAT Analyzer with eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traceview is there for the rescue. See the official documentation http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html .

You can check the memory leaks through it too. DDMS provides a UI for profiling also.